# React Native Alert Sound

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I want to play an alert sound every time something happens in my application, but I haven't been able to find a package or a method to do it. My react native version is 0.69

I tried a package called react native sounds but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried custom sound for push notifications. So you should try the same thing maybe it will work.✌️

https://embusinessproducts.com/how-to-add-a-custom-push-notification-sound-on-ios-and-android-with-react-native-firebase-and-fcm/